# how to start windows CE 5.0 / 6.0 development

Tags: windows-ce

### Current Scenario:

I am a windows UWP developer. 
I am currently using VS 15 update 3 along with windows 10 OS on my machine.

### What I want to achieve?

I want to create a windows CE based Navigation system for my car.

### Problems getting started:

1. I wanted to know that can I develop for windows CE on my windows 10
   OS running machine?
2. Can I use C# to program my application (I've read about compact
   framework). If yes then how?
3. Which version of Visual studio should I use (Posts say VS 2008) but is     there any later version of VS i could use?
4. and to get myself started where do I start with assuming my ultimate goal is navigation based device for my car.

Guidance would be a great help.

Comment: atleast give a reason for the down vote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest (and, in all likelihood, last) version of Visual Studio to support CE 5.0 and 6.0 is Visual Studio 2008, which does run on Windows 10.

Getting your hands on a copy of VS2008 may not be easy though; an MSDN subscription albeit expensive would enable you to download it, or you could try and get it off eBay (assuming the license terms allow this, of course...)

CE 5.0 and 6.0 support .NET Compact Framework 2.0 and 3.5, but not the full .NET framework used on Windows PC's.

Just for completeness, CE 5.0 supports .NET CF 1.0 as well.

Comment: thank you for the answer. So I'll be able to use concepts of C# versions up till c# 3.0 right? Also would you be able to guide me in the right direction to get myself started on the platform?

Comment: Sorry, it's been a while and I don't remember which specific C# version is supported. As to getting started... install Visual Studio 2008 + the SDK for the device you'll be using, start writing code...

Comment: Sweet. I'll check it out thank you for the answers. I couldn't help but notice you mentioned +SDK for the device, are there different SDKs for different devices? Or did you mean the compact framework with .Net

Comment: Depends on the device you're using. Often you can get away with selecting just a generic "Windows CE" target in Visual Studio, when creating your project

Comment: Copy that! Thanks car!

Comment: I just have one last query, Do I develop for smart device or windows forms to finally deploy it on a windows CE navigation system

Comment: If we are talking about the project type, then it would be the Smart Device one. Windows Forms is for desktop Windows

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121939/discussion-between-aditya-sharma-and-carsten-hansen).

Comment: I deeply apologize but I got to know I tried developing an application for Windows CE under smart devices and selected the windows CE platform. The issue is I can't find where to write designer code. Like we use XAML for Windows phone. Is there any designing language if yes which one? And where do I type it in VS2008? I'll really appreciate your response

Comment: From memory (others may correct me on this) CE 5.0 only supports Windows Forms, which means you don't write designer code as such, but use the point n click designer and the toolbox in VS2008 to put together your UI. CE 6.0 on the other hand does support a limited version of Silverlight, I'm not sure though how much that version has in common with the XAML-based framework used in Windows Phone. In short, the frameworks and tools used for CE 5.0 and 6.0 are a lot more primitive than those used for Windows Phone today

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So if I switch to windows CE 6.0 to CE 5.0. I'll be able to use XAML for designer code but the silverlight libraries are for c++ not for C# right? Also, using drag and drop for windows CE how do i make an adaptive layout if all I do is set up margins and lengths? I promise it'll be the last question. thanks

Comment: I don't have any actual experience with CE 6.0 Silverlight and its use of XAML (sounds like another SO question :-) ) Windows Forms doesn't offer much in the way of adaptive layouts except docking and anchoring controls. Of course third-party libraries may exist, or you could roll your own. Then again, if you are targeting a specific device, maybe an adaptive layout isn't required at all?

Comment: Great! old habits of using adaptive layout makes handicapped if it's not available. Thank you so much for all the help.